# Copy leafs from a Binary Search Tree (Recursively), in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am trying to copy leafs (recursively) from a BST to a new BST that include the copied leafs only. Here is what I did:

```
27 void tree::copy_leafs(node * src, node *& dst) {
28     if (!src)                                 //Case 1: current node is NULL
29         return;
30     if (!src->left && !src->right) {          //Case 2: current node is a leaf
31         dst = new node;
32         dst->data = src->data;
33         dst->left = NULL;
34         dst->right = NULL;
35         copy_leafs(src->left, dst->left);
36         copy_leafs(src->right, dst->right);
37     } else {                                  //Case 3: current node is NOT a leaf
38         copy_leafs(src->left, dst);
39         copy_leafs(src->right, dst);
40    }
41 }
```

The code seems to be right when it comes to compiling, visiting leafs and copying them. However, the root of the new tree (`dst`) always has one leaf only (the last leaf). Any ideas?

**EX of the problem:**

- Say that `src` had these leafs: `4`  `15`  `19`  `23`
- After this function, `dst` will only have `23`.

Comment: Lines 35/36 are no-nops.

Comment: All calls to `copy_leafs` pass the same `dst`. The only place where `dst` is assigned a value is line 31. Therefore the function is always going to create a leaf-only tree (possibly by overwriting `dst` several times).

Comment: S***!! That's true, it's only a leaf (dead end)! @melpomene

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix that? @melpomene

Comment: If your input is `src={ data: 2, left: { data: 1, left: null, right: null }, right: { data: 3, left: null, right: null } }`, what should the output be?

Comment: it should be `1` and `3`. (inorder) @melpomene

Comment: But what should the tree look like?

Comment: Doesn't look to me like you're copying the current node.

Comment: i have been trying to do the same thing and haven't been able to solve it very well yet. my best solution was using an insertion function and calling that every time a leaf is found but it isn't the best. it already has O(N) for the traversal of the tree being copied and each insertion call will be O(log(N)) of the new tree. with only a few items it isn't bad but with a lot more that isn't really the best case scenario.

edit: words

Comment: Additionally you might want to assign NULL to dst when src is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Since the bug has already been found in the comments, here's a very superficially tested solution.

You can't blindly copy nodes; you need to create a BST structure.
You can do this by first copying the leaves to the left and the leaves to the right and then joining them in a suitable way.

Since you start with a BST, the greatest node in the left copy is smaller than the smallest node in the right copy.
This means that you will get a BST if you replace the leftmost left-pointer (which is null) in the right copy with the root of the left copy.

This may lead to a very unbalanced tree, of course.
If you want to balance it, you need a more sophisticated solution, which is left as an exercise.

Assuming this node structure:

```
struct node
{
    int datum;
    node* left;
    node* right;
    node(int v) : datum(v), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
};
```

it would look something like this:

```
node* copy_leaves(const node* tree)
{
    if (!tree)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    if (!tree->left && !tree->right)
    {
        return new node(tree->datum);
    }

    // Not a leaf; recurse
    node* left_leaves = copy_leaves(tree->left);
    node* right_leaves = copy_leaves(tree->right);
    if (!left_leaves)
    {
        return right_leaves;
    }
    else if (!right_leaves)
    {
        return left_leaves;
    }
    else
    {
        // Locate the leftmost node in the right tree.
        node* smallest_right = right_leaves;
        while (smallest_right->left != nullptr)
        {
            smallest_right = smallest_right->left;
        }
        // And attach the left leaf tree.
        smallest_right->left = left_leaves;
        return right_leaves;
    }
}
```

I believe it's possible to make `copy_leaves` also give you the leftmost node, which saves some top-down traversals, but it complicates the code so I'm leaving that as an exercise.

Answer (score -1):

```
void copy_leaves(node * src, node *& dest)
{
    if (!src) return;

    dest = new node(src->data); // this should zero out the pointers, assuming you make one.

    copy_leaves(src->left, dest->left);
    copy_leaves(src->right, dest->right);
}
```

Comment: this is just going to copy the entire tree, not just the leaves.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!